# LTK: removing character echo in Entry widget

Tags: user-interface, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, ltk

Is there anyway to have remove echoing of characters being typed in the Entry widget of LTK?

For the CLI interface I use the c-string function (alien routine)

```
(sb-alien:define-alien-routine getpass sb-alien:c-string (prompt sb-alien:c-string))
```

Not quite sure how to apply this in LTK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `-show` (`:show`) option of the entry to the placeholder character you want. You can do it during widget creation:

```
(make-instance 'ltk:entry ...... :show "*")
```

or later:

```
(ltk:configure my-entry :show "*")
```